# VBA: How come pausing my macro makes it faster?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

As suggested yesterday, I'm splitting my question into two parts, although I think they might be connected:

I have an Excel-macro that basically works, but it gets slower the more sheets are added by the macro. when I create only a few sheets (~100) it's ok but sometime it creates up to a few hundred sheets and every sheet is a different report, and I have to keep all the sheets. An then the issue starts.

Afer the macro creates all those sheets, I do tings like sorting an printing. But before the macro continues with this tasks it takes a very long time, depending on how many sheets I've just produced.

A few years ago I had an issue with a slow macro. Then I found the hint with a forced pause. I've tried it with this macro again, and it improved the speed by a huuuge amount of time. How come a pause speeds up a macro?

The code is a bit longer so I've reduced it to address the issue and marked it in the code:

```
Sub My_Issues()
    Dim ColumnLetter As String, item As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sheetCount As Integer, TotalRow As Integer, TotalCol As Integer
    Dim uniqueArray As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Get unique brands:
    With Sheets("Brand")
    .Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Sheets("Sales").Columns("R:R").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim uniqueArray(1, 1)
    uniqueArray(1, 1) = .Range("A3")
    Else
    uniqueArray = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value
    End If
    End With

    TotalRow = Sheets("Sales").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    TotalCol = Sheets("Sales").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, TotalCol).Address, "$")(1) 'Num2Char
    sheetCount = 0 'Counter for statusbar

For x = 1 To UBound(uniqueArray, 1)
    item = uniqueArray(x, 1) 'item=Brand
    'Filter sales for each brand:
    With Sheets("Sales")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(TotalRow, TotalCol)).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=item
    End With

    With Sheets("Agents")
    'Delete old...
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Clear
    '...and get new
    Sheets("Sales").Range(Sheets("Sales").Cells(3, 2), Sheets("Sales").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    'List with all agents
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Agents").Range("A2", Worksheets("Agents").Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    With Sheets("Report")
    .Range("I4") = cell 'Copy agent and update the formulas within the report
    .Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Report")

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value 'Replace all formulas with values
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell

    sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
    If sheetAnz Mod 10 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = sheetAnz 'Get statusupdate every 10 sheets
    End With
    Next

'->Issue: I create up to 400 sheets and when I want to continue and do some sorting of the sheets for example it takes a very long time.
'But if I add this break for a second, it works reasonably fine again. Why is that? Does vba needs the break to catch up with itself?
'Since the issue is not the sorting and the other stuff after the pause.

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'Continue with other stuff.... sorting sheets and so on

Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function  Rather than using copy and paste, you can say `destinationrange.valule=sourcerange.value`

Comment: My best guess is that the pause forces some sort of memory clearance on things that are dealt with, so when the code resumes with sheet sorting etc. there's less unnecessary stuff to deal with. If you find that getting rid of copy/paste and use `sheet2.range("A1").value2 = sheet1.range("A1").value2` methods speeds things up then it's probably just a clipboard memory issue?

Comment: I use that in parts of my code. You may refer to the part with 'xlCellTypeVisible'. There i didn't manage with the value-approach, so I did the copying. If it can be done with values, I guess we are talking about fractions of a second only that are saved.

Comment: I also think it's memory clearence but I never found written "proof" for that.

Comment: This is one of the reasons it slows down if you have a formula with array functions on a sheet. It consumes a lot of computer's resources.

Comment: @Dy.Lee So you mean I should change the 'uniqueArray'? Could you please state one of the other reasons you are mentioning?

Comment: I don't know the state of your Excel file, but as a general rule of thumb, an Excel file with a lot of formulas slows down as data or other content accumulates, and at some point you can't use the file itself. . If the size of the data is large, it is better not to manage the file by the formula, but by the value.

Comment: You're surely right, that's why I replace all formulas with their values with ''ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value''. So I think that's not an issue, as I have formulas only in one master-report sheet.